# how to know all remote connections of a LAN host in PHP or Java?

Tags: network-programming

I mean:

```
TCP    192.168.0.190:22218    69.59.196.211:80       ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.0.190:22237    72.14.203.102:80       ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.0.190:22322    69.59.196.216:80       ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.0.190:22324    64.34.80.173:80        ESTABLISHED
```

but not localhost.

Say,you are 192.168.0.191,but you want to know network connections of 192.168.0.190.

Answer (score 0):

You could always just exec() the netstat command and parse the response...

Comment: Unless you setup some sort of service on the remote machine there is no way to determine this. That would be a security breach.

Answer (score 0):

This can not be done in php, unless perhaps the client side is running a gtkphp app or similar, then using exec as a previous poster suggested.

Answer (score 0):

exec() is the only way, if you can't exec then you can't do it.

you also cannot get the remote connections of a different host!